# How to implement real-time data synchronization between a Flutter app and Firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

I'm building a Flutter app that needs to synchronize data with a Firebase backend in real-time. Specifically, I want to be able to update data on one device and have those changes immediately reflected on all other devices that are using the app.

I've heard that Firebase has some built-in features for real-time data synchronization, but I'm not sure how to get started. Can someone provide a code example or some guidance on how to implement this functionality?

Here's some sample code that I've been working on to retrieve data from Firebase and display it in a ListView:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class MyDataModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  int quantity;

  MyDataModel({this.id, this.name, this.quantity});

  MyDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    quantity = json['quantity'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['quantity'] = this.quantity;
    return data;
  }
}

class MyDataService {
  final DatabaseReference _myDataRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('myData');

  Stream<List<MyDataModel>> getMyData() {
    return _myDataRef.onValue.map((event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value == null) {
        return [];
      }

      final List<MyDataModel> myData = [];
      event.snapshot.value.forEach((key, data) {
        myData.add(MyDataModel.fromJson({...data, 'id': key}));
      });

      return myData;
    });
  }

  Future<void> addMyData(MyDataModel data) async {
    await _myDataRef.push().set(data.toJson());
  }

  Future<void> updateMyData(String id, MyDataModel data) async {
    await _myDataRef.child(id).set(data.toJson());
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyDataService myDataService = MyDataService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<MyDataModel>>(
      stream: myDataService.getMyData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        final List<MyDataModel> myData = snapshot.data;

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: myData.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(myData[index].name),
              subtitle: Text('Quantity: ${myData[index].quantity}'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => EditMyDataScreen(myData[index]),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```